# Android: Hide a LinearLayout onKeyDown

Tags: android

I have a LinearLayout which holds a couple of buttons. To give the user more (drawing)space on the screen i want to hide this LinearLayout on Menu press:

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {

                if (showButtons) {
                    showButtons = false;
                    LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.buttonLayout);
                    laySize = lay.getHeight();

                    go2trimsecond();
                } else {
                    showButtons = true;
                    go2trimsecond();
                }
```

I thought i just save the height in if(showButtons), change the maxHeight of the layout to 0 and change it back on if(!showButtons), but unfortunatly i was thinking wrong, since there is no setMaxHeight.
Any idea how i should do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi stefple,
             It would be a good help if you elaborate your need. But what i understood from your recent post i wanna suggest one solution.

As you have instance of your layout as lay.

just do lay.setVisiblity(View.GONE) or lay.setVisiblity(View.INVISIBLE);
and in case you wanna show it again just do

lay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Remember one thing View.GONE will free the space occupied by your linear layout whereas View.INVISIBLE will keep the space occupied but just hide the layout.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change layout height. Since LinearLayout is also a View, you can call [setVisibility(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) method on your layout.

Comment: Thanks a lot, was going to answer that this doesnt work. I tried setVisibilty(0) but with Suresoft's answer i got it working.